# Jabber-based server and client application in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, chat, xmpp, voice

I have implemented an application which currently supports text chat. Now I want to implement voice chat and later video chat in it, but I have less time provided by client. :(
So I am planning to go for some open source code in Cocoa, which I can use and easily incorporate into my application.

After analysis on the internet, I found that a Jabber-related client/chat server application should be best according to my requirements.

I have found that there are several Jabber-based client-server applications but they are mostly written in Java, C, or C++ and are not Cocoa-oriented.

Can anyone suggest me some links or code for a Cocoa-based Jabber server and client application?

Also I want to ask that let's say I have a server application built in C and a client application built in Cocoa, then will I be able to transmit text and multimedia messages between client nodes?

Comment: just to inform you all I have found a wonderful jabber chat application from this link: http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/, but it performs only text chat but I am planning to add voice chat!

Answer (score 1):

in xmpp no generic support of media transfer, but you can use xmpp as signal channal to establish media session (see jingle for example)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: http://softwarelivre.sapo.pt/sapo_msg_mac

Leapfrog is using the PSI-Core.

Would like to see some progress.